# Spring mvc's request is not getting mapped with urls like having /? (slash question mark)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Here is Spring servlet definition:

```
    <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When I hit URL `/comic/ff109e3c-3728-43bb-9074-6a6f8ec74755?param1=value1`, I get a "HTTP 200" response but when I hit `/comic/ff109e3c-3728-43bb-9074-6a6f8ec74755/?param1=value1`, Spring MVC gives a "HTTP 404" response code.

Here is the requestmapping annotation from Spring MVC's controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/comic/{uuId}", "/comic/{uuId}/**", "/player/{uuId}/**", "/player/{uuId}" }, method = { RequestMethod.GET,
            RequestMethod.POST })
```

What do I have to do to make an URL like `/comic/ff109e3c-3728-43bb-9074-6a6f8ec74755/?param1=value1` will work?

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

`/comic/?param1=value1`  is wrong way for path parameter, write `/comic/yourvalue1` , If you have probability that uuid can be empty then you can define request mapping like this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/comic", "/comic/{uuId}", "/comic/"} , method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: Prashant / and ? both at a time is not correct in URL

Comment: you can either use queryparam or pathparam

Comment: do you mean, spring does not support both at a time ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123337/discussion-between-prashant-thorat-and-jekin-kalariya).